# How to show a row from DB and update it value with gridview

Tags: asp.net, database, data-binding

My goal is to load a row from db to a webform and let the user update it's value .

The user searches an id (i have a stored procedure for that), how i show that data from the

row nicely in the web page through the dal layer. After the data is shown on the page the user need to update a cell in the row and send it.(the part of updating is not the problem).

in other questions how should the dal method should look and how i integrate it's result in the presentation layer (the aspx webform).

thanks a lot.

p.s.

I've done a little reading but i don't know what exactly to use data object, data row , data table, object data source. i'm little confused by the data bind alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options and one of them is using ObjectDataSource.

If it is going to be a single record you can use DetailsView or Formview else you use GridView.

Check the tutorials here:

[Displaying Data with ObjectDataSource](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-vb)

[Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials)

Comment: tnx alot, I have one more minor question, how can i catch in the dal layer the result of store procedure which does select query and should return one row? 

according to the first useful tutorial i know how to connect the objectData to my details view. how can i enter the objectData that result?

p.s.

is details view can apper in editing view, so the user can edit the a single cell?

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly you want just one record correct? In that case check this: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/declarative-parameters-cs. And yes detailsView can appear directly in Edit View for editing by setting it's property CurrentMode="Edit". Check this too:http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs